Accessing to a serverless SQL pool specifying the system-assigned managed identity in SSMS
I'd like if it is possible to access to a serverless SQL pool specifying the related system-assigned managed identity in SSMS.
For a Synapse workspace named f.e. asaws, the system-assigned managed identity is asaws, the name of the workspace.
Thanks

To grant permissions for Synapse Workspace, you can follow these below steps:

Select Access control (IAM)
Select Add > Add role assignment.




In the Members tab, choose Managed identity, then click Select members.
Select your Azure subscription.
Under System-assigned managed identity, choose Synapse workspace and select a specific workspace.
On the Review + assign tab, click Review + assign to assign the role.

Reference: Retrieve system-assigned managed identity using Azure portal
